# Laravel 5 performance issues

Tags: php, performance, laravel-5

I've started using Laravel 5 for a medium-complexity app, and although I was expecting a minor performance impact the framework is proving to be worryingly slow.

I've been developing in a local environment, running Wamp on a Windows 8 environment, i7 with 8GB Ram.
I've run `php artisan optimize` and enabled apc and I'm still not getting reasonable results.

Should I expect much higher hardware requirements compared to a app developed without any framework (No MVC, Routing, Templating)?

For testing I've setup the simplest route:

```
public function test(){
    return 1;
 }
```

and even this way the request takes ~250-300ms (Chrome)

This is particularly important for my API functionalities.

I'm wondering how much my app could be optimized in a production server environment to minimize response time.

- Is it possible to remove unused Laravel components?
- Does laravel provide other optimization mechanisms?
- Are there better caching alternatives to apc?
- Would an SSD be of any help?

Any help on this topic is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you must work on a Windows platform, use XAMPP instead of WAMP, it provides better performance and less bugs while developing. Besides it simulates a closer environment to that of linux servers.

Answer (score 0):

The results you are showing are not okayish indeed. 
Do you have any Linux environment to measure performance of the same "test route application" there? 
I believe results might be much better.

As simpler option to check: you can try to run [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead) and measure performance within virtual Linux-machine.